# Enumerating MudTabpanels inside Mudtabs and activating/deactivating it

Tags: mudblazor

I have the following code

```
<MudTabs Elevation="4"  Rounded="true" Centered="true" @ref="tabs"  AlwaysShowScrollButtons="true" Color="Color.Info" Style="@($"color:{Colors.Pink.Darken1};")" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text1" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text2" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text3" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text4" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>


                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text5" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text6" Disabled="@isDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text7" Disabled="@isRiskSummaryDisabled">
                        
                    </MudTabPanel>

                    <MudTabPanel Text="Text7" Disabled="@IsExceptionDisabled"  ID="exctab">
                       
                    </MudTabPanel>

@code
{
    MudTabs tabs;

 private void DisableAllTabsExceptExceptionTab(int _index)
    {
       
        try
        {
            var list = tabs.Panels
            foreach(MudTabPanel mtp in list)
            {
                mtp.Disabled = true;
               
            }
            tabs.ActivatePanel(_index,true);
            StateHasChanged();

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to disable all tabs except one. However the code is not disabling the tabs.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't come close to compiling. Also, it is not clear how/when you are calling `DisableAllTabsExceptExceptionTab`. Could you edit your question and create a snippet to make clear what it is you're trying to do? https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile and there are missing informations about what errors do you encounter.

Anyway, here you are a working example:

```
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(()=>DisableAllTabsExceptExceptionTab(6))">Disable All Tabs Except Last One</MudButton>

<MudTabs Elevation="4" Rounded="true" Centered="true" @ref="tabs" AlwaysShowScrollButtons="true" Color="Color.Info">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text1"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text2"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text3"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text4"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text5"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text6"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Text7"></MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

@code {
    MudTabs tabs;
    private void DisableAllTabsExceptExceptionTab(int _index)
    {
        var list = tabs.Panels;
        foreach(MudTabPanel mtp in list)
        {
            mtp.Disabled = true;               
        }
        tabs.ActivatePanel(_index,true);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

You can try it here:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOwdOvcBzeOlVVoT